# How can I make a header taller in WordPress?

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I want to make the header of [this](http://www.hermanuscamp.co.za) WordPress page taller. I found advice [here](https://en.forums.wordpress.com/topic/can-not-make-gateway-header-taller?replies=7#post-2470017) that I should use the following code in the homepage template CSS file:

```
.full-container {
  min-height: 390px;
}
```

The CSS file looks like this:

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying the home page panel. Requires SiteOrigin page builder plugin.
 *
 * Template Name: Page Builder Home
 *
 * @package vantage
 * @since vantage 1.0
 * @see http://siteorigin.com/page-builder/
 * @license GPL 2.0
 */

get_header();
?>

<div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">
        <div class="entry-content">
            <?php
            if ( is_page() ) {
                the_post();
                the_content();
            }
            else if( function_exists('siteorigin_panels_render') ) echo siteorigin_panels_render('home');
            else echo siteorigin_panels_lite_home_render();
            ?>
        </div>
    </div><!-- #content .site-content -->
</div><!-- #primary .content-area -->
```

Where must I put the suggested code in?

Comment: Never mind. I will insert a text field and use html to make the text larger.

Answer (score 0):

In a [Child Theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) or `wp-content/themes/vantage/style.css`

Comment: I mean, I don't understand the code. I want to copy-paste the code, but I don't know where to paste it.

Answer (score 0):

The code you showed there as the CSS style is not the style at all, thats a costum page template named "Page Builder Home".

You should open style.css which is found directly on the theme folder. At the very end of style.css add the lines of css:

```
.full-container {
  min-height: 390px;
}
```

If you dont know how to difference css files from php/html files then you definitely are in the wrong business and you should let the work be done by the pro-s.

having said that, hope my "solution" works for you.